# List<> as parameter to a dll function in c#

Tags: c#, dll

I have a dll written in C (CVI), I should use the functions in C#. My problem is, that in some functions there is a list (ListType) as parameter.

CVI function definition:

```
int DLLEXPORT InserInList(ListType listSendRequest, char *cRequest)
```

Code in C#:

```
[DllImport("DLL_Test.dll", EntryPoint = "InsertInList", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int InsertInList(List<RequestItem> listRequest, string Request);
```

With this kind of implementation an exception will be thrown, that generic types can not be marshaled. Is there any chance to pass a list as a parameter to a dll-function?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with a *gasp* `ArrayList` ?

Comment: `List<T>` in C# is actually array.  The `ListType` in your C program looks like an linked list.  I don't think it can be marshaled to `List<T>` or even `ArrayList`.

Comment: I've tried it with ArrayList. With that runs the code at least without an error through. However the list (ArrayList) doesn't contain the item, I'd like to insert. Any idea? Thanks.